# Registering a RISC receiver endpoint for Google fails with 403 Forbidden "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect, google-signin, secevents

I'm trying to register an API endpoint to receive RISC security events from Google and have followed their [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#register_your_receiver) for doing this. However, I've been struggling to get a successful response from their side and I always get the following unhelpful error:

```
HTTP 403 Forbidden
Response payload: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Now, this error message is nowhere mentioned in their [error code reference docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#error_codes). I've tried researching but there are very few resources on the topic. I tried to apply most of the stackoverflow answers on the topic with no success.

I'm pretty sure I configured everything correctly in the Google Cloud Console. For instance, I have enabled the RISC API for my project:
[image]

Additionally, I assigned the right roles and access rights to my service account:
[image]

I'm also following their [code suggestions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#auth_token) to generate the JWT for my account and I think it's being correctly generated because when I change something I get a different error. Here's the code for generating the JWT:

```java
String createJwt() {
    String issuer = "https://accounts.google.com";

    PrivateKey privateKey = myPrivateKey;

    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey);
    Date issuedAt = new Date();
    Date expiresAt = new Date(issuedAt.getTime() + 3600000);

    return JWT.create()
            .withKeyId("MyPrivateKeyId")
            .withIssuer("MyClientEmail")
            .withSubject("MyClientEmail")
            .withAudience("https://risc.googleapis.com/google.identity.risc.v1beta.RiscManagementService")
            .withIssuedAt(issuedAt)
            .withExpiresAt(expiresAt)
            .sign(algorithm);
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or have any suggestions to fix the problem?